# Is CMS independent from programming languages?

Tags: drupal, content-management-system

As the title suggested, can I use CMS like Drupal with other programming languages like Java for jsp? I want to know this before investing time to learn.

I mean whether I can use Drupal or similar CMS with Java or Ruby or C ... or not. To be more specific, may I process data in Java at back end and send to the CMS for it to do the update automatically?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Are you asking whether you can use Drupal with Java, or if there is a CMS-system for Java similar to Drupal. Or something else?

Comment: I mean whether I can use Drupal or similar CMS with Java or Ruby or C ... or not. To be more specific, may I process data in Java at back end and send to the CMS for it to do the update automatically?

Comment: Yes, you can. I elaborated on a few options in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mix and match languages/frameworks/cmses in web applications. There is nothing that forbids this, although it is usually inelegant, frequently wasteful (in terms of system resources), and generally a pain to maintain and extend. I've down this before in the past, merely for the sake of expediency, or when migrating old data, however you are better off using one framework and getting good with it.

If you really want that sort of flexbility I'd recommend [django](http://djangoproject.com) which is an extremely flexible and capable web framework for python. There are several CMSes that have been implemented on top of it (and you could roll your own pretty easily). [Django-cms](https://www.django-cms.org/) is one of them. It has have very flexible routing and if you wanted to you could easily implement different parts of your application with different languages/frameworks. Django also has a feature which makes it particularly adept at integrating into existing projects, [it can inspect your existing database and generate the models needed to interact with it.](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models)

There are a few basic approaches you could take if you want to mix and match.

1. Configure certain urls point to one application and other urls point to another. For instance you could do:

   - http://mysite.com/cms     -> drupal (or some other cms)
   - http://mysite.com/blog    -> wordpress (or a django app, or a rails app, or whatever)
   - http://mysite.com/gallery -> some other application
2. Use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) and do your front-end with one language/framework and write the back-end stuff in another. You'd use AJAX to call your backend services from the client's end.
3. Use a job/task queue like [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) (which integrates really nicely with django).
4. Use messaging to communicate between different parts of your application, with for instance [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) or [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/).

Comment: Note that while you *can* mix languages to deliver different parts of your website, it is a non trivial thing to do, you need to implemented services, proxies/load balancers that forward to the responsible server and more to be able to integrate them. You can't directly run Java code inside Drupal for example. So to be able to mix them, you need to know all involved technologies/programming languages. So missing PHP knowledge for example is IMHO not a reason to do the data processing in Java, because you will also need to write PHP to integrate it. There are reasons to do this however...

Comment: One reason is that you might need to process large amounts of data in short time. One such example is http://mollom.com, a spam prevention system that provides a Drupal module, which then runs within Drupal, written in PHP but does send all comments/content through a XML-RPC to an external service that is written in Java to be able to process the hundreds of thousands of requests.

Comment: It *can* be pretty trivial depending on what you need to do (and how difficult you want to make it). Using messaging with RabbitMQ or ZeroMQ is pretty easy, REST/XML-RPC is also pretty simple to implement...and hey if you want you could just call system("echo noooooo", $retval);!

Answer (score 1):

No you can't bind it,

Since the one main reason is both Php and JSP require different types of Web Container.

And drupal is made in Php so you cannot bind Java with jsp even using native library api.